# Locally change the font family

Tags: posts, html, css

I'm using the standard Wordpress theme (*WordPress Default 1.6* by Michael Heilemann).

The standard font for my articles is a sans-serif font.

I'd like to display, for a sentence only, a serif font (*Times* for instance).

I didn't find a way to do this. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a WordPress question but I'll answer it anyway. The first thing you need to know is CSS is your friend. You'll want to do something like this:

In style.css
`.serif-class {font-family: "Times", "Times New Roman", serif;}`

Then using the html view inside of your post:
`<span class="serif-class"> This is an important sentence </span>`

See more on [Span Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp)